# Spring Boot Bean could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Hello I'm learning Spring Boot and I'm working on a simple project. I have this problem when I try to execute the tests. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong :(

My project Github is here: https://github.com/emicovi/GildedRose_SpringBoot

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field itemRepository in com.gildedrose.gildedRose.DBLoader required a bean of type 'com.gildedrose.gildedRose.ItemRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

I tried many solution already posted on the net but I was not able to fix.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. We prefer a [mcve] as text in the question... if you need to link to a github repository, it's probably too much code to wade through. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you have excluded `DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class` from `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

`@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})`

This is the issue. DatasourceAutoConfiguration.class is required for running integration test cases with H2 db. Please don't exclude it and also add H2 dependency in pom.xml.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Also, you need to add empty application.properties file in resources folder like this.

[image]

After this issue will be resolved.

Comment: Good to know that your issue is resolved